# Is there any scriptural basis for this jinx in Hinduism?

Tags: scripture, superstitions

A common belief these days is to not say good will happen for sure lest you jinx it for the person/yourself. For e.g. "I didn't say anything to him as I was afraid I might jinx him"

I was wondering if the above has any scriptural basis or is it just superstition/folklore.

Comment: Well this tradition more of kinda, sounds like one of the foreign imported cultural vernacular nonsense. Something in similar lines like, existence of an Upanishad named as,                           ALLOPANISHAD. Anyway, it's a superstition or at best a lokãchara (लोकाचार) type superstition maybe.